# CSS overflow:hidden hide full child content at my page

Tags: css

I want to display some CSS3 animation inside a div box. So I need to apply `overflow:hidden` for unwanted overflow.

In case of test at fiddle its work well. But If I apply `overflow:hidden` at parent div in my page, its not display child content anymore.

Please see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Loqesumx/1/) and help me.

```
My Css:

.movcontainer{
position: absolute;
top:200px; 
width:100%;
height:89%;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:55;
display: block;
border: 2px solid blue;
}
.contentbody{
position:fixed; 
top:0px; 
width:100%; 
height:100%;
border: 2px solid green;
}
.parent{
position: absolute;
top:10%;
left:10%;
width:80%;
height:80%;
border: 2px solid red;
text-align:center;
display: inline-block;
clear: both;
overflow:hidden;
}
.child {
background-image:url('http://fallmeeting.agu.org/2012/files/2012/09/Dust-and-Aerosols-SWIRL-graphic.jpg');
border: 2px solid green;
width:600px;
height:600px;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin:auto;
transform-origin: center;
}
```

**Update:**

Here I have two more div which create for few positioning. One `.movcontainer` and other `.contentbody`. Here `.contentbody` have fixed position and problem occurred here. But this two div is essential for me.

Here is my [update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Loqesumx/2/)

Comment: does the parent of your `.parent` element have position relative on it?

Comment: It works.(Chrome 45.0.2454.101 m)

Comment: @Pete nothing without above child

Comment: If it's working in fiddle and not working on your live site, then the code you gave in fiddle isn't representative of the code that's on your live site. You need to figure out what's different between your live site and your fiddle until the fiddle breaks the same way your live site does. Then we can help.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: I solved my problem by `position: fixed;` on `.parent` div. Thank you all

Comment: If you've found a solution to your question, consider adding it as an answer so the question can be closed.  That way your answer can also be used for future reference in the community for anyone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by replace `position:absolute` by `position:fixed` on .parent div.